# How to add view component on button in react native?

Tags: react-native

My question is :  I want to render a view component on every key press. But its just calling 2 times only by default. Button is not working. I don't know where I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thanks.

```
function renderBottomComponent() {
        console.log("here");
            return (
                <View>
                    <Content />
                </View>
            )

    }


  <View style={styles.List}>
                       <View> 
                           <Content abc={this.mhandler} hel={'hahah'}/>

                       </View>

                       {this.renderBottomComponent()}

                </View>



<Button title="Add more" color='green' onPress={this.renderBottomComponent} />
```

Comment: What do you mean by render component on keyPress?

Comment: means  i want to add  components in the list upon key press ! Kindly tell me

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471921/programmatically-add-a-component-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class YourClass extends React.Component() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        renderComponent: false
    };
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandler() {
    this.setState({renderComponent: !this.state.renderComponent})
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.state.renderComponent && <YourComponent/>}
            <Button title="Add more" color='green' onPress={this.onClickHandler} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

I hope that will help you